# Spring integration: mail:outbound-channel-adapter suceed or failed

Tags: email, spring-integration

Using spring integration, how to know if a mail is sent succefully or failed, because I should handle the result.
My code:

```
<mail:outbound-channel-adapter channel="outboundMailChannel"
        mail-sender="mailSender" >
    </mail:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the send fails, the adapter will throw an exception which you can handle on the `error-channel` of whatever's upstream of the adapter. Or, you can use a [ExpressionEvaluatingMessageHandlerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to take different actions based on success or failure.